# Understanding webgl min/mag filter texture artifacts in orthographic projection?

Tags: glsl, webgl

### Summary

- Flickering and shimmering of image plotted on a geometry where the viewport exceeds the size of the screen. I am using an orthographic projection for the camera. In this case, it is tied to THREE's `OrthographicCamera` where the `left,right,top,bottom` parameters are `-w/2,w/2,-h/2,h/2` and `h=height of data` and `w=width of data`.
- I am rendering a geometry that is larger than the screen viewport, but with the `left,right,top,bottom` defined above as fitting to the dimensions of the data, the entirety of the data fits on the screen.
- This geometry is broken into PoT tiles. I am using a LUMINANCE format for texture with a barebones fragment shader (the data itself is float32)
- The view matrix is based on an orthographic projection where the frustum extends to the extent of the geometry (so the entire geometry is in view)
- I have both enabled/disabled mipmap generation and have seen the same results below

### Issue

For sufficiently large geometries (often 10-100x larger than the viewport) this causes some annoying artifacts that cause the texture to "shimmer" effectively changing the visual representation of the data.

### Examples

Here is an example where the camera is panning down the Y-axis (down) in very small values relative to the viewport dimensions and you can see the texture actually appear to change:

[image: Shimmering Example #1]

This aliasing effect is definitely apparent in datasets like the one above (a raster plot of a signal)

Here is a second example that shows it a lot more.

[image: Shimmering Example #2]

My suspicion is that this is an artifact of the minfilter when there are many texels per pixel. What the heck is going on here!?